# How to select distinct ID's, but then show the complete rows?

Tags: php, sql-server

was searching the stack, but couldn't find a specific answer. I work at the hospital and want to make our daily life easier. We collect data from placed catheters and visit the patients once or sometimes twice a day. I wrote some php to store this information (SQL Server 2012). There is one table dbo.patients:

```
|ID|PatientID|Station|Name  |Catheter|Room|VisitDate|Visit
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |123456789|ACHI   |Muller|PDK     |12  |12.12.17 |all fine, nothing special
|2 |123456789|ACHI   |Muller|PDK     |12  |13.12.17 |catheter removed
|3 |234567891|GYN    |Meyer |PDK     |4   |04.07.17 |pain in the back, raised bolus
|4 |123456789|ACHI   |Muller|PDK     |12  |14.12.17 |no infection, dismiss
|5 |234567891|GYN    |Meyer |PDK     |4   |05.07.17 |still pain, raised up to 12
|6 |234567891|GYN    |Meyer |PDK     |4   |06.07.17 |non functional, removed
```

ID ist auto-increment at database and not entered at the form.
PatientID is a unique value at the hospital.
All other columns could probably be the same (e.g. 10 Catheter a day or all Catheter = PDK or two Names are the same or they share the same Room...).
There will be approximately 20 entrys to the Database a day.

My aim is, to show a list of patients, who have a catheter at the moment. Therefore I need all columns, but only the latest VisitDate - that means, that the PatientID isn't allowed to show up twice. The Output with the given example should look like:

```
|ID|PatientID|Station|Name  |Catheter|Room|VisitDate|Visit
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|4 |123456789|ACHI   |Muller|PDK     |12  |14.12.17 |no infection, dismiss
|6 |234567891|GYN    |Meyer |PDK     |4   |06.07.17 |non functional, removed
```

I already have the table in php, showing `SELECT * FROM dbo.patients`, but I need this filtered and I don't know why. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT`, what filtered the PatientID well, but it only returns one column and I need the whole row.

Through searchingstackoverflow I found something similar and tried it out:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY PatientID 
        ORDER BY VisitDate
    ) AS rnum,* 
    FROM dbo.patients
)
SELECT * FROM t a WHERE rnum IN (
        SELECT MAX(rnum) FROM t 
        GROUP BY PatientID 
        HAVING t.PatientID=a.PatientID
 )
```

It works, but I don't know if its appropiate or if anyone alse has a less complicate idea. Additional, I dont really get, If he displays the latest entry.

Thanks in advance!

dirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
   order by row_number() over(partition by Patientid order by VisitDate desc)
```

Other approach you can use row_number in outer query:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_number() over(partition by PatientId order by VisitDate desc) from yourtable ) a
   Where a.RowN = 1
```

Output as below:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----------+------+------------+-------------------------+
| Id | PatientId | Station |  Name  | Catheter | Room | VistitDate |          Visit          |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----------+------+------------+-------------------------+
|  4 | 123456789 | ACHI    | Muller | PDK      |   12 | 2017-12-14 | no infection, dismiss   |
|  6 | 234567891 | GYN     | Meyer  | PDK      |    4 | 2017-07-06 | non functional, removed |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----------+------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: I used ur first approach - thank you so much, it works! But what does [Name] mean? I just deleted it and it still works.

Comment: Your name column

Comment: Yes, but what is its purpose in the given query? For what do I need it? I can't figure it out :). Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep based on your requirement partition by PatientId itself is enough